# Xamarin Forms Android Target API level Warning

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, google-play

for the last days, whenever I deploy a new Xamarin Forms app to Google Play Store, I get the following warning when from Play Store:

> Your app currently targets API level 15 and must target at least API
>   level 26 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimised for
>   security and performance.
>
> From August 2018, new apps must target at least Android 8.0 (API level
>   26).
>
> From November 2018, app updates must target Android 8.0 (API
>   level 26).

But Target Android Version is set to "Automatic - user target framework version (API 27)" while Minimum Android version is "Override - Android 4.0.3 (API level 15)".

I don't think that from August 2018 onwards, only apps for Android 8 or higher are allowed in the Google Play Store, right? So currently I could of course ignore the warning, but what do I need to change for August?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Counter-intuitively with Xamarin, when you set the target SDK to use the latest version it actually targets the minimum version. You need to set the target SDK to a specific version.

In other words, change from "Automatic" to a specific version.

More info here:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1163

Comment: Interesting! Thanks Lewis, I'll try that on my next release and add a comment whether it worked! Thanks!

Comment: I changed from Automatic to 8.1 and got the following error so thanks a lot for your help!! Error XA5207: Could not find android.jar for API Level 27. This means the Android SDK platform for API Level 27 is not installed. Either install it in the Android SDK Manager (Tools > Open Android SDK Manager...), or change your Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that is installed. (XA5207)

Comment: also not working when i set the exact target version as level 27, i still see this warning

Answer (score 0):

The apps will keep working, but you should consider targeting API 26 for the warning not to be shown to your users. It's a win for all sides: your app is safer, Google is happy and your users don't see a warning that will make them trust your app less than they otherwise would.

**EDIT**: you probably know this, but you need to set `targetSdkVersion` in your `build.gradle` file to `26` to meet the requirement for the warning not to be shown.

P.S. [here](https://www.androidpolice.com/2017/12/19/play-store-require-new-updated-apps-target-recent-api-levels-distribute-native-apps-64-bit-support/) (article) you can read more about it.

Comment: Thanks John, but as written in my question: Target Version IS already API 27, and also article linked by you says that Target Version should be 26 but minimum might be 14 or else. So that's the configuration I already have. Don't you get a warning in your Xamarin Forms application when you update?

Answer (score 0):

I think something is probably wrong with your build process, and even though you think the target API is 27 it isn't. You can verify your target API/SDK using the following command:

```
aapt dump badging my.apk
```

The target sdk will appear on a line like this

```
targetSdkVersion:'27'
```

So you could use a tool like grep to find it quickly.

If aapt gives a result of 26 or 27 and Play store still gives the warning then it is a bug with Play, and you should report it via Play console support. You can contact them via the help menu (the "?" icon) in the Play console.

Comment: aapt does not seem to be in SDK Command prompt from Visual Studio....? Do you know where it is?